# Автозаполнение поля ввода формы в Django

Tags: python, django

На html-странице поля Продукт, Мастер, Клиент, Статус заказа отображаются в виде ComboBox. При большом количестве записей, заполнение формы будет затягиваться (тратится время, на поиск нужного содержимого ComboBox).
Как сделать так, чтобы вместо полей ComboBox были поля Input, начав писать в которых, уже подставлялись бы совпадающие с вводом данные, содержащиеся в таблицах базы данных?

Класс Order.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    idProduct = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Продукт')
    idArtisan = models.ForeignKey(Artisans, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Мастер')
    idClient = models.ForeignKey(Clients, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Клиент')
    timeLim = models.DateField(verbose_name='Срок выполнения', blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата принятия заказа')
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Комментарий', blank='true')
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Статус заказа')
```

Форма OrderForm

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('idProduct', 'idArtisan', 'idClient', 'timeLim', 'comment', 'status')
```

Код html:

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: вроде то что вам нужно https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/ 
Ну это из готового

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то призодилось использовать на практике **[django-ajax-select](https://django-ajax-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**, отличная штука. Советую.